# How to expand TB Megamenu in opposite direction so it won't go outside of the site?

Tags: 7, routes, navigation

I am using [TB Mega Menu](https://www.drupal.org/project/tb_megamenu) for my drop down menu that has three columns with width: 665px and height: 335px.

I want to do something like this:
There are total 8 menu tabs.
When I click on first 6 menu tabs it expands to right as it is appearing. But when I click on last two menu tabs it should appears to the left. So, it won't go outside of the site.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with css using the last-child or nth-child psuedo elements on the li element of your menu list.

As a rough example...

```
.menu ul li {
  width:200px;
  margin-left:0px;
}

.menu ul li:last-child {
  width:200px;
  margin-left:-100px;
 }
```

Or for the last two out of 8 menu tabs...

```
.menu ul li {
  width:200px;
  margin-left:0px;
}
.menu ul li:nth-child(7),
.menu ul li:nth-child(8) {
  width:200px;
  margin-left:-100px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @ Collins..
It solved my problem..

Also to solve this, I have added margin-left to that data id.

[data-id="847"] .tb-megamenu-submenu.megadrop-down-menu.dropdown-menu.mega-dropdown-menu.nav-child{
     margin-left:-200px;
}

Thank you @Collins